# Can't get offsetHeight from React Ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get size of `div` element inside in `React render` method. But always it comes `offsetHeight,offsetWidth` as `0`.

I can see actual value of `offsetHeight,offsetWidth` when `console.log`.

How can I get actual size of container div ref element after component rendered?

Here is my implementation.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            height:0,
            width:0,
        }
        this.containerRef = React.createRef()
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log(this.containerRef)
        //saw offsetWidth and offsetHeightSize (300,700)

          const {offsetHeight,offsetWidth} = this.containerRef.current
          this.setState({
              width:offsetWidth,//getting 0
              height:offsetHeight //getting 0
          })

    }
    render() {
         const {width,height} = this.state
        return (
            <div ref={this.containerRef}>
              {`width:${width}-height:${height}`}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: The code looks fine... I pasted it on CodeSandbox and it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-payne-qwrdi
Maybe is something related to the way you are using the component?

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro thanks. I am using just react-jss for styling.

Comment: @tcetin I have the same problem, how do you solve this?

Comment: One reason for getting 0 as size is that you are using your component in some container that has animation (e.g. in Dialog). When animation starts size can be 0 and after it ends there is right size. You can probably listen onAnimationEnd callback of your container, and read value after that.

Answer (score 1):

React Hook solution

```
const useResize = (myRef) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)

  const handleResize = () => {
    setWidth(myRef.current.offsetWidth)
    setHeight(myRef.current.offsetHeight)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    myRef.current && myRef.current.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)

    return () => {
      myRef.current.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    }
  }, [myRef])

  return { width, height }
}


const MyComponent = () => {
  const componentRef = useRef()
  const { width, height } = useResize(componentRef)

  return (
    <div ref={componentRef}>
      <p>width: {width}px</p>
      <p>height: {height}px</p>
    <div/>
  )
}
```

Class-base Solution

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.myDiv = React.createRef()
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    console.log(this.myDiv.current.offsetHeight)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div ref={this.myDiv}>element</div>
    )
  }
}
```